# Google Sheets: Search for matching words in a list based on the last word in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

UPDATE

[image]
Now it only need to scan the whole row instead of only the cell next to it.

I am quite new to google sheets and I want to achieve the following:

Lets say we have **list 1:**

```
Red apple
yellow banana
orange orange
juicy melon
```

We also have **list 2** that looks as follows:

```
giant red apple
yellow banana
orange orange purple
water melon
```

*Now I want to write a function where I loop through each item in List 2 where I check if each item is in list 1, based on the last word of List 1.*
When a match has been recognized, in list 2, the cell *must turn green.*

So If we compare list 2 with list 1:

```
giant red apple -> exists because apple is in list 1, cell turns green
yellow banana -> TRUE because banana is in list 1, cell turns green
orange orange purple -> False because purple is not in list 1, cell stays white
water melon  -> TRUE because water is not in list 1, cell turns green
```

**Now I hit a wall, I have absolutely no idea what to do, any idea how I can achieve this or any hints?**

Comment: double check the conditions you imposed because something is not right.. look especially at the only solution that, according to you, returns FALSE...
`water` **IS** in `list1` and, even if we compare with last word of the list (`melon`), it **IS** in `list2`

Comment: Also specify which cell(s) should turn green.

Comment: @Daniele edited my list also I specified which colors everything should turn

Comment: there continue to be inconsistencies.
You say "water melon -> TRUE because water is not in list 1, cell turns green" but we have to find the LAST word of list1, that is "melon", and that last word is also in list2, so it is TRUE because melon is in list1. Do we really have to compare every word of list2 with the last word of list1?

Comment: "orange orange purple -> False because purple is not in list 1, cell stays white" ... BUT purple isn't the last word of list1 (it is orange) and orange IS in list2

Comment: "Now it only need to scan the whole row instead of only the cell next to it."  that formula scan ALL the A column... write in the file I posted where and what it does wrong

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AZM78etZTCm87xG_S-8kTlJHe0C98a0dzgCRVrtdG2U/edit?usp=sharing) satisfies you and if I understood correctly.

If `A2:A` contains the list1 values, the conditional custom formula for the `B2:B` (list2) range is:

```
=if($A2="",,iferror(search(trim(right(substitute($A2," ",rept(" ",len($A2))),len($A2))),B2)))
```

where the trim part:

```
=trim(right(substitute($A2," ",rept(" ",len($A2))),len($A2)))
```

gets the second word of list1

Comment: Yes exactly like this, but now if im not mistaking, it check the cell next to it, but I would like it to scan the whole list 1. See the description above for more info about what I mean. But it is very close to what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Already thank you for the explanation and help @Daniele!